# angular build size with sass is huge

Tags: angular, sass

So, I'm working on big app and all components have their own sass file style (we use ViewEncapsulation.Native) but I build `npm run build --stats-json --prod --aot` and check the stats with https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/ I get this

[image]

All those big orange blocs on the right are sass.shim.ngstyle.ts files and each one is like 195k !

Comment: @KevinNielsen. Those are the polyfills that are required incase shadowdom functionality is not present in the browser. I am not sure what kind of answer you are expecting. Can you give some more details?

Comment: I think you've already tried this but: have you got `gzip` on server side? Have you got `uglify` in webpack?

Answer (score 3):

so after some investigation the problem was that every component was importing the `_mixins.sass` but the mixins was also importing `bootstrap-custom.sass` file that was quite large in size.

the solution was to import `_bootstrap-custom.sass` from the `_main.sass` and import `bootstrap-custom-variables.sass` from `mixins.sass` file because some custom mixins needed those variables.